# Calculating Residues

Tags: residue-calculus, complex-integration

I want to calculate this integral
$$I:=\int dk^{0}\frac{e^{-ik^{0}(x^{0}-x'^{0})}}{\left(\left(k^{0}\right)^{2}-|\vec{k}|^{2}\right)} $$
for that I recall the Residue Theorem:
$$I=2\pi i \left\{ \mathrm{Res}\left[\frac{e^{-ik^{0}(x^{0}-x'^{0})}}{\left(\left(k^{0}\right)^{2}-|\vec{k}|^{2}\right)},k^{0}=|\vec{k}|\right]+\mathrm{Res}\left[\frac{e^{-ik^{0}(x^{0}-x'^{0})}}{\left(\left(k^{0}\right)^{2}-|\vec{k}|^{2}\right)},k^{0}=-|\vec{k}|\right]\right\} $$
My question is, how do I calculate those residues?

Comment: The two poles are simple (assuming $|\vec k| \ne 0$) and there is a simple formula for the residue at a simple pole

Comment: Yes you are right. But I'm missing a sign, I obtain $I=2\pi i \frac{1}{2|\vec{k}|}\left[e^{-i|\vec{k}|(x^{0}-x'^{0})}-e^{i|\vec{k}|(x^{0}-x'^{0})}\right]$, but my book says that the result is with a plus sign instead of the minus. Do you think that sign is important? @kiwi

Comment: Is $x^{0} - x^{'0}$ positive or negative? If positive, you need to complete your contour in lower half plane, your contour will circle around the poles clockwisely and pickup an extra minus sign. If negative, you need to complete your contour in upper half plane, your contour will circle around the poles counterclosewisely and no extra minus sign there.

Comment: @Anuar, what book is that, please?

Comment: "Electrodynamics and classical theory of fields and particles" by A. O. Barut p. 153. @DonAntonio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us try first to write that integral in a little less horrible , more usual, way:

$$I:=\int\,dz\frac{e^{-iz(x_0-x'_0)}}{(z^2-t^2)}=\int f(z)\,dz$$

Now:

$$Res_{z=\pm t}=\lim_{z\to \pm t}(z\pm t)f(z)=\frac{e^{\mp it(x_0-x'_0)}}{\pm 2t}$$

so the integral equals

$$I=\frac{2\pi i}{2t}\left(e^{-it(x_0-x'_0)}-e^{it(x_0-x_0')}\right)=\frac{2\pi}{t}\sin\left(t(x_0-x_0')\right)$$

and this agrees with your result, so I think your book's wrong .

The above is, of course, assuming the integral is around a path enclosing *both* poles of $\,f(z)\,$ .

Comment: OK. Thanks for your help. I'm going to study the consequences of that missing sign.

Comment: (-1) see my comment in question about sign of $x_0 - x_0'$.

Comment: First, I think you rush a little too much to downvote (even if the answer is wrong). Second, why do you think the sign of that exponent matters *at all* to calculate the residues of the integrand, which only are $\,z=\pm t\,$ , with my notation, or to determine the path which, most probably, is given?

Comment: It may be a little rush, but I downvote because the user has accepted your answer. I'll remove the downvote once the user notice this or you update your answer.

Comment: Oh, it doesn't matter...to me, at least. Your downvote doesn't affect me in the least, yet it'd still be nice if you could address my past comment, where I question your reasoning. Perhaps I'm wrong, of course...

Comment: The sign of exponent does matter. On the upper half plane, $|e^{iz}| \to 0$ while $|e^{-iz}| \to \infty$ as $|z| \to \infty$. So if you have something like $e^{-iz}$ in your integrand, you cannot evaluate your original integral along real axis by completing the contour in the upper half plane. Instead, you need to complete the contour in the lower half plane. The end result is you will pickup residues from completely different set of poles and get a different answer.

Comment: What? What has the real or imaginary axis to do here? The OP is talking about residues as he wants to carry on a complex integral on closed contour on the plane, and this is clear from the fact that I mentioned this in my answer and he said nothing. This is why I cannot yet understand what has the exponent's sign (assuming, btw, that $\,x_0-x_0'\in\Bbb R\,$, which *isn't* given) to do with the evaluation of the residues

Comment: The OP is following a book which compute the time-part of [Green's function/propagator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator) of [Klein-Gordon equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation) in momentum space. It is an integral defined over the real axis of the frequency/energy $k_0$. The $x_0 - x_0'$ is the time difference between the observer and a reference point for initial data. For casual dependence, one want to study the parameter range $x_0 - x_0' > 0$.

Comment: Perhaps so, but he didn't write anything about it. Oh, well: it really doesn't matter.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yup. If the OP doesn't provide enough detail, it is hard for anyone to figure out what the OP really need.

Comment: Actually the solution of the book is $2\pi i\frac{1}{2|\vec{k}|}\left[e^{-i|\vec{k}|(x^{0}-x'^{0})}+e^{i|\vec{k}|(x^{0}-x'^{0})}\right]\theta(x^{0}-x'^{0})$ where $\theta(x^{0}-x'^{0})=0$ for $x^{0}-x'^{0}<0$ and $\theta(x^{0}-x'^{0})=1$ for $x^{0}-x'^{0}>0$.

Comment: Here the book is using the contour $C_R$ which is above the poles in the $k$-plane, according to a figure.

Comment: Well Anuar, but then you meant to ask about doing complex integration in order to solve a *real* integral, and then Achille's is right: one must know what the sign of the exponent is in order to get that the integral on the curved non-real part of the contour goes to zero when the radius increases...and you did NOT mention all this!

Comment: In fact the integral is real, but the book uses a complex variable integration method. Now I understand that they add or subtract to the poles a small imaginary part $i\epsilon$ in order to lower or raise them and compute the integral with different contours. But it results that the integral only converges when one choose the correct sign of the difference $x^{0}-x'^{0}$. Maybe I'm forgetting details, but the main idea is this. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: @DonAntonio since the issue is settled, I try to undo my downvote but the system won't allow me until you edit your post. What a strange system.

Comment: @Anuar there are 4 possible choices of assigning the small imaginary part $i\epsilon$ to move the poles away from the real axis. They correspond to different casual behavior of the Green's function/propagator. The most common one is the one you see, the *causal* propagator, which will be non-zero only when $x_0 > x_0'$. The wiki page of [propagator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator) have a little bit more info on this.

Comment: @Achille, thanks for trying. Anyway, you can "edit" my post by adding, say one period or one comma, and then you can undo your downvote.

Comment: @DonAntonio I don't have enough reputation to edit other people's post.

Comment: I have edited it now, @achillehui

Comment: @DonAntonio, done.